# GWT: setInnerHTML unescapes attribute values

Tags: javascript, gwt, escaping, html-entities

This string: `<a onclick="doit('&#39;')">...</a>` is received from the server-side and needs to be set as the inner HTML of an element.

When I use `Element#setInnerHTML` the string is converted to `<a onclick="doit(''')">...</a>`, i.e. unescapes the HTML entity to the character it represents.

How can I preform the inner HTML assignment with no entity conversions?

*Clarification: The inner HTML assignment only unescapes entities inside attribute values.*

Comment: try escaping the ampersand: `&` --> `&amp;`, so the result is `<a onclick="doit('&amp;#39;')">...</a>` before the HTML injection.

Comment: @EliranMalka thanks, it seems that setInnerHTML only unscape entities inside attributes. so when I apply your solution those inside attributes are corrected but those outside are broken instead (`&amp;` outside attribute is converted to `&amp;amp;` and is viewed as `&amp;` instead of `&`)

Comment: why not use escaping only for the cases in question (only for attribute values)?

Comment: because this html fragment is also included in html pages (as well as ajax load) and escaping needs to be consistent on server.

Answer (score 2):

The `setInnerHTML()` implementation itself poses no issue, since its only role is to assign a property value to the underlying JS object, as can be seen by examining `Element`'s source code:

```java
public final native void setInnerHTML(String html) /*-{
    this.innerHTML = html || '';
}-*/;
```

The problem lies within the browser, innocently following the *Charset Entity References guides* in the *HTML Document Representation* specifications and parsing your entities, which are **allowed** (thus get parsed) inside attribute nodes.

#### From the specification:

> Authors should also use "`&amp;`" in attribute values since character
>   references are allowed within CDATA attribute values.

#### Solution

On the server side (or via a filter or a designated client proxy), escape all special characters **inside attribute values** with the corresponding HTML entities, e.g.:

```html
<a onclick=\"doit('&amp;#39;')\">...</a>
```

#### References on W3C

- [HTML Document Representation · Charset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html).
- [Character Entity Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html).

Comment: 1. I think you have misunderstand the spec. It means that **literal `&`** should be escaped to `&amp;` but `&` in `&#39;` is not literal. 2. The word **also** in the sentence you have quoted from spec refers to previous sentence which generally states that literal `&` should be escaped and then adds also in attribute, so special treatment for attribute can not be concluded. 3. If I do so I will have broken html (incorrect attribute values) when served as html page instead of ajax response.

Comment: **1.** as the html entity appears inside a string, the ampersand becomes literal. **2.** you can, of course, escape all typical cases (e.g. in text nodes), but you didn't mention having a problem in other situations. **3.** treat json type response differently, what's the problem?